# django-versatileimagefield issues: 'No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin' when deploying to Google App Engine Flex

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-app-engine

Since upgrading to `django-versatileimagefield==2.0`, I just can't get it to play nicely with Google App Engine. Using it as is comes up with the error that others have reported:

`ImportError: failed to find libmagic. Check your installation`

I've read similar problems that mention adding `python-magic-bin==0.4.14` to the requirements. That seems to rectify the problem locally.

When I deploy to Google App Engine, though, it fails when when trying to install `python-magic-bin` with:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin==0.4.14
No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin==0.4.14
```

I am using the App Engine Flexible environment with Python 3.7.2. I've tried numerous different ways of installing the required packages and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using python-magic - `python-magic==0.4.15`.

**UPDATED:**

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#using_c_libraries_with_python) libmagic-dev package is not pre-installed on flex environment, so you will need to switch to custom runtime as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime).

After that just add libmagic-dev installation to the Dockerfile with:

> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev

Comment: That was one of the things I originally tried. Unfortunately I get the error `ImportError: failed to find libmagic. Check your installation` when the app tries to launch.

Comment: Yes, actually got same error. The best solution i have right now is switching to custom runtime as described here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime and adding libmagic installation to Dockerfile with `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev`. Seemed to work for me like that.

Comment: Default flex environment doesn't have libmagic-dev package https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#using_c_libraries_with_python. Updated the original answer.

Comment: If anyone is facing permission related errors, then ```sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libmagic-dev``` should be run.

Comment: God bless you! this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error mostly occurs if python-magic-bin is not available for the OS. Removing it from your requirements.txt file should fix the problem. See this [issue.](https://github.com/Patrowl/PatrowlDocs/issues/5)